# Relationship between optimal action-value function and optimal value function

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning

I would like to clarify on the relationship between the optimal action-value function of an MDP and the optimal value function as I often get confused between them.

Is it possible to express one of the function using the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deterministic case**

If $V(s)$ is the optimal value function and $Q(s,a)$ is the optimal action-value function, then the following relation holds:
$$
Q(s,a) = r(s,a) + \gamma V(s')
$$
where $r(s,a)$ is the single transition reward, $\gamma$ is the discount factor, and $s'=f(s,a)$ is the next state, given state $s$ and action $a$.

**Stochastic case**
$$
Q(s,a)=r(s,a)+\gamma\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)V(s') 
$$
where $p(s'|s,a)$ is the transition probability to new state $s'$.

**For both cases**

The relation is the following:

$$
V(s) = \max_a Q(s,a)
$$

Comment: @NeilSlater,  my version is for the deterministic case only. Yours is correct for the stochastic case.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you for inputs. Feel free to modify.